# No MediaQuery widget ancestor found. Scaffold widgets require a MediaQuery widget ancestor

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, flutter-layout, flutter-design

I am new to flutter, BUILT an app showing graphs in flutter. When i run the code a red screen is appearing showing the above error

> No MediaQuery widget ancestor found. Scaffold widgets require a MediaQuery widget ancestor.

I have cleared all the errors except this one.

[Full link of the code](https://gist.github.com/ImVasav/a3bb10e2f28ef7118cc224955b9b7e87)

[image: link of screenshot error]

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your scaffold to MatertialApp or you can make a class and in that class call GraphScreen like this

```
   void main() => runApp(const MyApp());
 
  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {      
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
  
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: GraphScreen(),
  
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: was helpfull...i appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Check you `main.dart`, and in the MyApp (Or whatever you named it) class, you should wrap it with MaterialApp. It should fix the problem.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget  {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Graphn',
      home: GraphScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: was helpfull...i appreciate